# Youtube onStateChange not firing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

```
player = new YT.Player(A, {
                    videoId: z.videoId,
                    height: z.height,
                    width: z.width,
                    playerVars: {
                        autoplay: (z.autoplay ? 1 : 0),
                        autohide: (z.autoHide ? 1 : 0),
                        controls: (z.showControls ? 1 : 0),
                        loop: (z.loop ? 1 : 0),
                        rel: (z.showRelated ? 1 : 0),
                        fs: (z.allowFullScreen ? 1 : 0),
                        theme: z.theme,
                        wmode: "transparent"
                    },
                    events: {
                        'onReady': function (event) {alert("onReady")},
                        'onStateChange': function (event) {alert("onChange")}
                    }
                });
```

This code works fine on development environment. On our testing servers, we are using Adobe Sitecatalyst for tracking, which is also binding onStateChange.

Could someone please suggest, how to make multiple onStateChange work, or I can bind this event in a specific namespace, or any other probable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind Sitecatalyst to a different, custom-named event, and then in the function that onStateChange triggers, you could dispatch that custom event:

```
'onStateChange': function (event) {
   alert("onChange");
   var event = new CustomEvent('siteCatalystOnStateChange', { 'data': event.data }); // here's the event SiteCatalyst will listen for. It's a custom event so you can pass additional parameters; the listener function is passed the object
   elem.dispatchEvent(event); // elem is the element that SiteCatalyst is listening on
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but the problem was something else with the js load sequence.

Comment: @Ankur just for reference could you explain the problem with the js load sequence? I'm running into the same issues that you are

Comment: @totalNewb YT js might take more than expected time to load. So what I did was have the player initialization within a callback, and callback was called from a polling method which checked for typeof YT !== "undefined", you can use setInterval or clearInterval for polling, or any other way you like.